# Transfer of Hebrew filenames from Windows - question marks

Tags: windows, raspbian-buster, locale

I have set up Hebrew localization on Raspbian Buster. Hebrew works OK, and I can save files with Hebrew filenames. However, files with Hebrew filenames which I transfer from Windows appear in the file manager with question marks instead of Hebrew letters. The contents of the files are correctly displayed, the problem is only in the filenames.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I have now resolved this problem. It appears that when I transfer directly from the mounted folder on the windows computer, it work correctly. However, the first time I transferred the files was by means of a USB memory stick. For some reason, files with Hebrew filenames on the memory stick appear as question marks, and remained so when transferred to the raspberry pi. Of course this is still a problem, but it is not one that prevents me from continuing my work.

Comment: How do you xfer the files from Windows to your Raspberry?

Comment: Sorry framp, the system doesn't let me add a comment. To answer your question, I mounted the windows folder and copied by dragging using the file manager, and also using luckybackup. The results were the same.